# Laravel Schema Default Value Function

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want the default value for my `Server` model's `sid` to be the uniqid() function to be run every time. Something like this, for example

`$table->string('sid')->default(uniqid);`

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an event listener to set the `sid` attribute on your model. You can do this using an event listener, model observer, or just a closure function inside your model's boot function.

```
// app\Models\YourModel.php

/**
 * Define model event callbacks.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->sid = uniqid();
    });
}
```

Comment: I like this method the best. Don't want to create a new event/listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, `MySQL` requires constants for the default. So, the default value must be a constant, it cannot be a function or an expression.

Only way is to allow the fields nullable and add `uniqid()` while creating records on the database like this:

```
$table->string('sid')->nullable();
```

Now, When you add records set `sid` value to `uinqid()` value

If you have model named `Table` then

```
$record = new Table();
$record-> -----
--------
--------
$record->sid = uniqid();
$record->save();
```

This is the way you can achieve.

**UPDATE**

You can set default value in model as well like this:

```
protected $attributes = array(
   'sid' => uniqid(),
);
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a method I can put on the Model to automatically do this on ::create?

Comment: @ThorCorreia I've updated my answer. you can use $attribute property override to achieve that.

Comment: @SagarGautam you can't call a function in the definition of a class property. See http://phpsadness.com/sad/2

Comment: @ThorCorreia yes you can use an observer to set this property on object creation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the easiest way

```
$table->unique('sid')->index()
```

Comment: Hi, from what I understand this simply generates a number starting from 1… but that would not be wise for my application, as users would be typing these server ID's in themselves, and it would be easy to join somebody elses game. I'm not password protecting these servers so that's not good.